# jQuery find children's first-child

Tags: jquery

I need help to use jQuery to select the **first kid** of each kid.

> .children().children() will select all
>
> .children().first() does not work

```js
$(function(){
  $('.form').each(function(){
    $(this).children().children().addClass('some class');
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> do not select this</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks all now solved, i picked this solution:

```
$(this).children().children(':first-child')...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.form').each(function(){
    $(this).children().children(':first-child').addClass('colorclass');
  });
});
```

```css
.colorclass{
background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div>
    <label>1st child</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> do not select this</label>
    <div>
    <label>Grand child</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> do not select this</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>2nd child</label>
    <input type="text">
<div>
    <label>2nd Grand child</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great works :+1. However it will also find grand grand children if match. I only want the children's first child.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same, not work, must be cached. Now works +2

Answer (score 1):

There were two way to add class to label element.

```
// 1. you can directly add label within selector
$(function(){
  $('.form div label').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('some class');
  });
});
// 2. second method as per your need is
$(function(){
  $('.form').each(function(){
    $(this).children().first().addClass('some class');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

## jQuery Docs

### [:first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

> While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to :nth-child(1).

```js
$(function(){
  $('.form').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div :first-child').addClass('some class');
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> do not select this</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

.children() will give you array of all the childNodes.

You are iterating on the all the form elements, you need to iterate over children of the form

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form').children().each(function() {
    $(this).children().first().addClass('some class')
  });
});
```

```css
.some.class {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> do not select this</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>I need select this</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```